# Read data from Advanced Format disk over USB adapter

Tags: hard-drive, usb, sata, advanced-format

I have a WD Green 6TB HDD with data on it. When I plug it into either macOS or Windows, it always shows as 18TB empty.

I'm using a SATA to USB 3 adapter to connect it, and it seems that it's lacking AF support. When I plug the device into my Windows PC through SATA, everything shows up fine.

HD Sentinel shows all SMART info when it's plugged in, even over USB, and hints at the 4k sectors.

Is there any way to use the device (read-only should be fine) over USB without buying a new USB adapter?

My amazon history says the adapter is called "CN Memory 75615" and 5 years old.

Comment: The adapter may be to old to communicate with a 6tb drive.

Comment: I have a very new one, but it doesnt include external power, so it can only power smaller drives. I'll try to figure out a solution to hook up power externally

Comment: The drive being advanced format really has nothing to do with your problem.  The drive might have 4k physical sectors, but it still presents itself to the host computer with 512 byte physical sectors, just like virtually every drive for a long time.  Your problem is probably that the SATA-to-USB bridge is doing sector size translation: that would make the drive appear 8x its true size and the partitions would be unreadable.  Few bridges are configurable in this regard, so you need a new adapter.